# Private WordPress blog, requires user registration approval, and allowing users to login with OpenID

Tags: plugins, user-registration, openid

I have the following scenario:

1. I have a private blog, running WordPress (self-hosted, not `wordpress.com` hosted), and I am using the [My Private Site Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-private-site/) to allow only logged-in users to see the site.
2. I want to approve all users prior to their gaining access to the blog, so I'm using the [New User Approve](https://wordpress.org/plugins/new-user-approve/) plugin to leave new user registrations in a `Pending` state.  According to [this documentation](http://picklewagon.com/wordpress/new-user-approve/):

   > Until a user is approved, the user will not be able to login to the site.

   Perfect, that's exactly what I want.
3. I'm using [Social Connect Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/social-connect/) to allow users to login with OpenID.  This will result in a WordPress user being created, that is linked to their OpenID identity, and (as expected) this WordPress user is in a `pending` state until I approve it.

However, apparently there is some miscommunication between these three plugins, because even though an OpenID login results in a new user being created with a `pending` state, they are still able to see the site.

Going through the "regular" WordPress account registration results in the expected behavior: user created in `pending` state, but unable to login until approved by an admin.

In summary, what I am aiming for is:

- Private blog, that only approved users can view.
- OpenID login as an option.  Actually, I don't mind if OpenID is a requirement: between Google, Facebook, Microsoft, LinkedIn and Yahoo. 100% of our blog readers will have an account elsewhere; But I'm also OK with users creating a WordPress user account if they really want to.

I see many plugins similar to `My Private Site`, many more similar to `New User Approve`, and still more similar to `Social Connect`. The possible permutations are overwhelming. I don't think I could possibly try them all, but perhaps a combination of them works?

Or may be there can be some custom CODE that'll make them work together?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there is a way.

First, you're going to want to install [the Member Access plugin](http://www.chrisabernethy.com/wordpress-plugins/member-access/) & [the official OpenID plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/openid/). Both of these are free

After configuring all of your pages and setting up the OpenID plugin, edit the robots.txt file in the Wordpress installation directory. Add the following line:

```
User-Agent: * Disallow: /
```

This will prevent crawlers from indexing your site, or discourage them at the very least.